# Can't use macOS Ventura VM with more than one CPU

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently created a macOS VM (Ventura 13) with VirtualBox (Version 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.2)). I first launched it with one CPU, and it booted. The downside was that the VM was very slow and practically unusable, so I set the number of CPUs to 4 (i have 8 in total). It won't boot up. After some tests I figured out that if I set the CPUs to more than one, the VM starts, restarts while booting and finally VirtualBox gives me the Guru Meditation error : "A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped."

Can someone tell me how to use the VM with more than 1 CPU ?

Here are the logs

[VBox.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKmYx.png)
[VBox.log](https://controlc.com/30079403)
Password for VBox.log : ilovechocolate

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: macOS has always been next to unusable on non-Mac hardware.